# Why does my Stack Overflow question, which was answered and can be found easily on the Web, not show up in my list of questions?

Tags: support

The question *[Can one concatenate two Perl scripts which use different input record separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431437/can-one-concatenate-two-perl-scripts-which-use-different-input-record-separators)* exists; I asked it. It plainly says "asked by Jacob Wegelin." Plus, I remember asking it. @Håkon Hægland answered it and @melpomene commented.

But I do not find it in my list of questions,
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461307/jacob-wegelin?tab=questions&sort=votes.

I have scrolled with my eyes through that list for "concatenate,"
and also electronically searched the list, and I do not find it. The list has **earlier** questions (one is from 2017), but not this one. What's going on?

Comment: You have used two different accounts. Check the user ID in the URL's

Comment: Jacob, don't edit your question into a different question. Also, the current answer already points you towards [what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 5):

You are using two different accounts.  The userID on the [Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461307/jacob-wegelin) in your [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/854533/jacob-wegelin) is 1461307; the account on which the question was asked is 7014400.  You should request a merge, see [Merging account help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to do that.

Comment: Might be helpful to link to the help doc on requesting a merge to help with the inevitable follow-up: "how do I do that?"

Comment: This is not a duplicate - because if someone doesn't know about duplicates or account merging, they won't know to look for it, so I hope that this question will stay up for non technical people who come up with the same question in future. Also, why the downvotes? Is it not a reasonable question?